# How to Redirect Registration page to My Account page if user is logged in?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a custom registration page and working fine unless I am logged-in. When I am login and click on my registration page it takes me to the registration page but it is blank. I want it to redirect the user if he/she logged-in to the my account page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in your header.php

```
$post = get_post();    
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        if($post->slug == 'regitrate-slug-here'){
            header( 'Location: /my-page-slug-here' );
        }
    }
```

or just paste the link in the if statement

```
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
    <a href="my-page">My page</a>
} else {
    <a href="register">Register</a>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Redirect custom Registration page to My Account page you should try small javascript something like this.

Write this code in your php file that you have created for registration.

```
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo("<script>location.href = '".home_url('my-account')."'</script>");
    exit;
}
```